# Apache LocationMatch everything except Shibboleth.sso

Tags: regex, apache

I want Apache to match all locations, except `/Shibolleth.sso/*`
I've a regEx wich does exactly what I want: `/^\/(?!Shibboleth\.sso)(.*)/` which can be tested here https://regex101.com/

Unfortunately, Apache 2.4.10 has a different RegEx support. The negative lookehead works, but everything except `/` is excluded. `/Search/Results` returns 400 Bad Request.

Apache 2.4 does not need to escape `/`, so my current LocationMatch is

`<LocationMatch "^/(?!Shibboleth\.sso)(.*)">`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does this really need a lookahead? Can’t you use a simple negated positive match instead? `!/Shibolleth.sso/`

Comment: I then have the same problem. `/` and `/Shibboleth.sso` works but all other URLS returns `404`.

Answer (score 0):

While it can be used, negative look-ahead regex-es are quite hard to understand. You also removed the '/' from your negative look-ahead regex giving it a slightly different semantic...

In such cases, I think is much easier to use the *If* directive and one of the Apache internal variables. Besides the regex being simpler this can be used, if needed, to match more complex conditions. See [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/Shibolleth.sso/#">
</If>
```